A short series of books in which the main character belongs to a race of beings who can create/reset the universe
I read the series a few decades back.
The main character winds up traveling with a troupe of companions who are mostly at odds with themselves. There are a variety of worlds/universes/realities in these hexagonal/octagonal places where they are created. The main character in his "natural" form most closely resembles a human heart. At the end of the adventure,  he hits a reset button on the universe and all of his companions wind up where they truly belong.

This could be the "Well of Souls"  series by Jack Chalker.
The premise is that an ancient alien race called the Markovians - who look like giant human hearts with six tentacles - wanted to create new forms of life and seed the universe with them.
They created a planet-sized computer, with the surface divided into hexagonal zones, each one with the ecosystem of a different alien world.
In the first book, "Midnight at the Well of Souls", a group of humans are mysteriously pulled to this world - the gimmick of the series is that everyone gets transformed into a random alien race - and they travel through several hexagonal zones to get to the entrance to the central computer. One of the characters reveals himself to be a disguised Markovian and uses the computer to transport the other characters to appropriate places.
One of the later books in the series has the central computer starting to break down, and needing a reset with universe-shattering consequences.

This sounds like a possible match to The Demonata series by Darren Shan, the first book was published in 2005. The series follows three main characters: Grubbs Grady, Kernel Fleck, and Bec MacConn. They all have pretty bleak and depressing backgrounds (Grubbs loses his sister and parents and cousin, Kernel loses his 'brother' and his parents, and Bec loses her entire tribe).
There is a magical object that exists within the Demonata world called the Origin Board, this board is shaped similarly to a chessboard (possibly the "hexagonal/octagonal places" you recall) where each square represents an entire mini-universe that could be filled to the brim with demons or be completely void (possibly the "worlds/universes/realities" you recall).
In the final book, Hell's Heroes, the trio reset the universe by using an incredibly powerful weapon called the Kah-Gash. Grubbs wants to tweak a few things, and make things better for some people (place people where they belong).
The "natural form is a human heart" character could possibly be a misremembering of the antagonist Lord Loss. His demon realm is entirely made of flesh, and where his heart should be is a hole filled with snakes.

Thanks so much for taking the time to respond. It turns out it was in fact the "Well of souls" series I was recalling. I have the link to the Darren Shan series saved; I'll be sure to check it out

@RJQ - you are very welcome, if you do give it a read I hope you enjoy! It would be great if you could formally accept Mazement's answer by clicking on the checkmark below the voting arrows next to their answer

I don't think this matches the description very well, but it's an amazing book series which I strongly recommend (even though this answer has spoiled some stuff :-) ) - particularly of note are the powerful endings of nearly every book in the series. @RJQ
